# When updating a field, Date modified trigger fires for all records instead of just the record that is being modified

Tags: sql, firebird, database-trigger

I am making a price list that automatically updates prices based on certain variables set.

When changing the cost of the items (i know my column names suck) or the time spent, the date modified field should change for only the record that had changed, instead the date modified field changes for every record on the table.  There are several triggers that fire in order to update the prices in the table.

I don't know how to split this file so that its easier to access the database but attached is a link to the database  (libreoffice base 6.2.3.2  using firebird 3.0 embedded)
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1dFedDfd2JtmvMk8ChVofDpSDN8hq0p_S

// Date modified trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRGDATEMODIFIED for "tblPart"
    before insert or update Position 100
AS 
BEGIN 
new."Date Modified" = current_timestamp;
END
```

//Set Total Price Trigger (last trigger to fire to set price all other triggers set the values for )

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRGSETTOTALPRICE for "tblPart"
    After insert or update position 99
AS
BEGIN
IF (old."Price" is distinct from new."Price" or old."Labor Price" is distinct from new."Labor Price" )
Then
Update  "tblPart"
Set "Total Price" = (CEIL(("Price"+"Labor Price")/10)*10)+9;
END
```

// trigger to set price that trigger TRGSETTOTALPRICE uses

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRGSETPARTPRICE for "tblPart"
    After insert or update Position 98
AS
BEGIN
IF (old."Cost" is distinct from new."Cost")
Then 
Update  "tblPart"
Set "Price" = "tblPart"."Cost" / ( 1 -(Select "tblVariables"."Margin"from "tblVariables")) ;
END
```

// Trigger that uses second table for values that wont accept the "new" psuedotable

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER TRGSETPARTPRICE2 for "tblVariables"
    After insert or update Position 98
AS
BEGIN
IF (old."Margin" is distinct from new."Margin")
Then 
Update  "tblPart"
Set "Price" = "tblPart"."Cost" / ( 1 -(Select "tblVariables"."Margin"from "tblVariables")) ;
END
```

// and my attempt to edit to work correctly

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER TRGSETPARTPRICE2 for "tblVariables"
    Before insert or update Position 98
AS
BEGIN
IF (old."Margin" is distinct from new."Margin")
Then 
 new."Price" = (select "tblPart"."Cost" from "tblPart") / ( 1 -(Select "tblVariables"."Margin"from "tblVariables")) ;
END
```

//code that should update all values when margin is changed

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER TRGSETLABORPRICE for "tblVariables"
    after insert or update position 98
AS
BEGIN
IF (old."Time Segment" is distinct from new."Time Segment" or old."Margin" is distinct from new."Margin" )
Then
    update "tblPart"
    set "Labor Price" = 
    Ceil((((select "Overhead with Margin" from "tblVariables") / (60/(select "Time Segment"from "tblVariables")))* Ceil(("Time to Complete"."tblPart")/( select "Time Segment"from "tblVariables"))));
END
```

//edit: Fixed code all runs , but the last code snippet feels like its implemented wrong but works nevertheless

Answer (score 1):

You are doing an unconditional update on all the rows in the tblpart table in the `TRGSETTOTALPRICE` and `TRGSETPARTPRICE` triggers. You shouldn't modify the targeted table in a trigger like this, instead you should use a **before** trigger and perform the modification on the `new` context variable. That context variable is modifiable in a **before** trigger exactly for this purpose.

That is, you should do:

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRGSETTOTALPRICE for "tblPart"
    before insert or update position 99
AS
BEGIN
    IF (old."Price" is distinct from new."Price" or old."Labor Price" is distinct from new."Labor Price" )
    Then
      new."Total Price" = CEIL((new."Price" + new."Labor Price") / 10) * 10 + 9;
END
```

and

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRGSETPARTPRICE for "tblPart"
    before insert or update Position 98
AS
BEGIN
    IF (old."Cost" is distinct from new."Cost")
    Then 
      new."Price" = new."Cost" / ( 1 - (Select "tblVariables"."Margin" from "tblVariables"));
END
```

Comment: on the bottom 2 examples that i just added to the main post , what can i do to update the main data table " tblPart" just for the values changed or i guess all the values should change on the other table because its a variable that is used by all records so that it doesn't need to be changed. but if i were to try to update only certain values that have been changed . how would i do it ?

Comment: tried it out just letting the variables table update all the values and it works fine it looks like but it just doesnt feel right, like i missed something. but its working now thank you for all your help

Comment: @aaronstevenson Maybe you should ask a separate question about that, and make sure to illustrate it with the necessary DDL and sample data.

Answer (score -2):

You need to do a join on the "updated" or "inserted" table to change only the records affected by the trigger. 
See a similar answer here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/118648/how-to-reference-only-affected-rows-in-after-update-trigger

Comment: That didnt work for me , i tried this code
 
CREATE TRIGGER TRGDATEMODIFIED for "tblPart"
 after insert or update Position 100
AS 
BEGIN 
 update "tblPart"
  set "Date Modified" = current_timestamp
 from  "tblPart" as upd,
  Join Inserted AS i
  on i.id = upd.id
  JOIN Deleted AS d
        ON d.id = i.id
END

Comment: it gives me an error of *Token unknown - line 7, column 5
*FROM

Comment: Firebird doesn't have `updated` or `inserted` tables. Triggers are fired per row, and the row is available in the `old` and `new` context variables.